Are bamboo leaves and chopped stems suitable for use as mulch?
In my garden, there is a bamboo plant (probably Bambusa vulgaris). I occasionally chop off 3 meter (10 ft) stems to reduce the spread of the bamboo plant, and leave the stems in a pile. In addition, there are lots of fallen bamboo leaves that have accumulated around the plant.
I am thinking of using the dried bamboo leaves and chopping up the stems (to make "bamboo chips") for mulching other plants. Are bamboo stems and leaves suitable as mulch? If so, should the stems be dried before being used as mulch? I am concerned about phytotoxicity issues or accidentally allowing the bamboo to reproduce in mulch.

Actual bamboo is unlikely to propagate from chopped up stems. Knotweed which some folks misidentify as bamboo would be more concerning for that prospect.

Probably not your particular bamboo, but an interesting read: https://ri.conicet.gov.ar/bitstream/handle/11336/67224/CONICET_Digital_Nro.f287c57f-149d-4846-aafe-f7c37461d979_B.pdf;jsessionid=F4CF905FE82F596674954B6D1E549DEF?sequence=3
